# C++ Correct design to iterate over members of derived instances

Tags: c++

I have a base class that holds a vector of pointers to derived classes and a virtual recursive method like this:

```
class Base
{
   std::vector<Base*> vec;
   
   public:
       Base(std::vector<Base*> vec = {}) : vec {vec} {}
       virtual ~Base() = default;
       virtual void f() const
       {
           if (vec.size() == 0)
               throw std::logic_error("Last children should implement f()")

           for (auto * part : vec)
               part->f();
        }

 }
```

The method `f()` is recursive and the last child of `Base` should override it. For example the following works
Where the first derived class is

```
class B : public Base
{
   B() : Base() {}
   virtual void f() const
   {
       std::cout << "In B\n";
   }
}

class A : public Base
{
   
    B b_,c_;
  
    public:

        A(B b, B c) : Base({&b_,&c_}), b_ {b}, c_{c} {}
}
```

If I call

```
B b,c;
A a(b,c);
a.f()
```

It will print twice `"In B"`correctly. Notice that `A` does not override `f()` so `Base::f()` is called, this loops and calls `B::f()` twice, once for `b` and once for `c`. However if I go one nested class more, for example by having

```
class C : public Base
{
    A a_;
    B b_;

    public:
          
          C(A a, B b): Base({&a_, &b_}), a_{a}, b_{b} {}
}
```

And I call `C::f()` the program segfaults. I suppose this is because there are some temporaries and their destructors delete the pointers held by `Base`. Is the solution to this to hold `shared_ptr`? or is there a better design? I cannot hold `unique_ptr` cause that would make all derived classes not copyable.

Comment: For completeness, you could really show the failing test snippet too. And fix the `public:` in `C` while editing the question.

Comment: BTW, I would do `virtual void preorder() = 0; void traverse() const { preorder(); for (auto * part : vec) { part->traverse();} /*postorder()*/ }`

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, I tried this and have the derived class implement `preorder()` returning a vector with pointers to their children. But those pointers are deleted (I suppose by temporaries and copies that `f()` may generate).

Comment: You have indeed issue by storing dangling pointers as pointed by answer.

Comment: Sure, but I still don't know how to solve my issue, so the question remains. Or rather both questions: is the solution to hold a shared_ptr? or is there a better design. Having a virtual returning pointers has the same problem as the current approach.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public C(A a, B b): Base({&a, &b}), a{a}, b{b} {}
> ```

Firstly, you can't have `public` there.

Your base points to the parameters of the constructor. Those parameters are destroyed when the constructor finishes and the pointers become invalid. Point to the members instead:

```
C(A a, B b): Base({&this->a, &this->b}), a{a}, b{b} {}
```

---

Note however that the implicit copy and move constructors and assignment operators of the class are broken because they will make the copied object point to the members of the copy source, rather than the members of the copy itself. So, you'll need implement those as well.

> is there a better design?

Possibly a better approach: Instead of storing the pointers in the base sub object, write a virtual function that derived classes can override, and which returns a range of pointers to children.

Comment: Thanks. I guess in my simplification of the class I didn't realize the parameters issue. In my real life example this is done with different names. I'll fix this in the question. As for the copy and move constructors i suppose indeed that's the problem but I don't know how to fix that. I